# What are the "suitable qualities to rename" a pet?

Tags: fallen-london

I'm having a bit of confusion here. I can "name a pet" since I don't want to keep it naming it "you" (is cruel), but I haven't found out what are these "qualities" that I need to fill to name it. So, how do I name a pet?

[image]

Comment: Fallen London calls *everything* a Quality; this might be a case where even the pet is called a Quality, and FL is claiming you don't have any pets. What pets do you have?

Comment: @PaulMarshall I don't have any pet, but the GUI makes me think that I do have one in my Lodgings by the way it's worded, and also it says "Name|0" indicating that I can and doesn't have (apparent) prerequisites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You require a minimum of one pet in order to rename a pet. Apparently, Fallen London doesn't properly check to see if you have a pet before allowing you to attempt the storylet that renames a pet.

Considering that there are dozens of possible pets, this makes a certain twisted sense: the Storynexus engine that runs Fallen London prefers to work with specific qualities rather than broad things like "one out of these three dozen Qualities". The devs went the lazy route and assumed that you wouldn't try to rename a pet if you didn't have one. (Otherwise, they would have to go back and update this storylet, and other storylets that let you change names, every time a new pet gets added. FailBetter games is a rather small company, so they went the easy route on this.)

Comment: Got a pet (a Raven) and I could rename it.

Answer (score 0):

You can name your pets through choices in certain Opportunity cards, but the best way to name your pets would be to go to your Lodgings and "Attend to matters of society and scandal". One of the options here will be to name your pet.

Comment: Seems like I do not explained well. I know how to, but **I can't** since I don't have "suitable qualities to rename".

Comment: Added an image to illustrate the problem